# How can I change which line ending style is used in the emacs shell (Carriage return / line feed)?

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, carriage-return, linefeed

I am working on a windows 10 machine using Emacs and plink to connect to a Linux development server.
I am able to start a shell in Emacs using `M-x shell`
and ssh to the server with `plink server`

When I press enter on my keyboard it's like I have pressed enter twice rather than once
`username@server>ls<enter>
file1  file2  file3
username@server>
username@server>`

I initially thought this had something to do with extraneous escape characters for the terminal as other questions have indicated. Opening a windows command prompt and ssh'ing to the server with plink output these extraneous characters and I was able to remove them with the following variables in my bashrc:

`export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
export PS1="\u@\H:\W>
export TERM=""`

The windows command prompt now properly displayed the plink session with no extraneous escape characters. Despite this, the Emacs shell still seemed to press enter twice for one press.

Next, I assumed there was a problem with the characters that were being sent by the enter key.

running `showkey -a` seems to explain the problem:

In a real putty window and in the Windows command prompt I got the following showkey output while in a ssh connection to the server:

`showkey -a
Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program
^M       13 0015 0x0d`

in the Emacs shell I get this output

`showkey -a
Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program
^M^J     13 0015 0x0d
         10 0012 0x0a`

It seems that the Emacs shell is sending a carriage return as well as a line feed when I press enter (the DOS line ending format). It makes sense then that enter is "pressed twice." Is there any way to change this behavior in the shell? I have seen the use of `set-buffer-file-coding-system` to tell Emacs to use Unix, Windows or Mac line endings. but this doesn't seem to work for me since I am in a shell.

Comment: What does `C-h C` tell you about the coding systems in use in that buffer?

Comment: Checking the coding system of the shell indicates that its input is a dos format. I did change the system to unix to no avail.

Comment: Which coding system did you change?  There are numerous options for various different purposes.  If you use `M-x set-buffer-process-coding-system` to set the process *input* to a unix coding system, does that resolve the issue?

Comment: This worked! 
I used M-x set-buffer-process-coding-system and set the input/output of the shell to iso-latin-1-unix.
running showkey -a now results in a linefeed rather than linefeed/carriage return when I press enter. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each inferior process, Emacs applies independent coding systems for the process input and process output.

In your case the coding system for input to the process will be a "dos" system, resulting in the CRLF pair being sent to the process for EOLs.

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-buffer-process-coding-system` to change these input/output coding systems interactively for the current buffer.  Bound by default to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

You could also use a hook to do so automatically for certain modes.  e.g.:

```el
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `shell-mode' behaviours."
  (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-unix 'iso-latin-1-unix))
```

As per the interactive prompts, the first argument is "Coding-system for output from the process" and the second is "Coding-system for input to the process".

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Communication Coding` for more information.